# How to get current user id Django

Tags: django, jwt

I am stuck with the JWT, can any one tell me how can I get user ID along with token.

My url.py :

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from scrumboard.views import UserDetail
from scrumboard import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
]
```

views.py:

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
```

The problem is that when i go to api-token-auth/, its only giving me the username and password and not the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the token, userid and username by following these steps:

Inside your `app`, create a `utils.py` file (at the same level where  serializers.py is placed).

Content of `utils.py`:

```
from .serializers import UserSerializer #you have already created UserSerializer

def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    user = UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data
    return {
        'token': token,
        'userid': user['id'],
        'username':user['username']
    }
```

In your `settings.py`, add

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'app_name.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler', #app_name is name of the app which contains utils.py
}
```

Now when you hit the api (api-token-auth/) to get the token, it will respond with token, userid and username.

Example of response:

```
{
     'token':'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImdhbmVzaG5lZ2lAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTI0NTAyNzIzLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImdhbmVzaG5lZ2kifQ.RxnYF1gwaYywSnnWC-ngrcZaw90lpD6Rq7jcbnEoZVk',
     'userid':1,
     'username':'ganeshnegi'
}
```

Comment: Thank you but im getting this error 'username':user['username'] SyntaxError: invalid syntax ... Any idea why ?

Comment: updated the answer. There was a comma (,) missing after the line 'userid': user['id']

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`django-rest-framework-jwt` docs](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/5c81e6550ffd5f47e512f4e33f579fe1b30fb226/docs/index.md#usage) this view only returns the username and password (emphasis mine).

> In your urls.py add [`url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)`] to enable obtaining a token via a POST included **the user's username and password.**

I wouldn't worry about not obtaining the id, you should be able to query the User table by username.

Comment: I see, so i cant obtain the id directly i should go throught username ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is? You should be able to make your queryset select using the username

Comment: I asked if i can get the user id directly from obtain_jwt_token but apparently i cant and as u said i should uery the User table by username

Comment: That is correct, the user's id is not included in the `jwt` so you should use the username to find the specific user